# submission accepted and appstore published the application, but suddenly removed from sale

Tags: flutter, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

It is a very strange thing that is now happened, I submitted an application into the appstore, the app published into the appstore, then suddenly another email sent after 5 minutes saying that:

```
The status of your app has changed to Developer Removed from Sale.
```

email sent before 5 minutes:

```
Congratulations!
Your submission was accepted for release on the App Store.
```

I am very confused right now, please help me what should I do.

[image]

[image: app review]

Comment: Did you try to re-submit the app or contact the support?

Comment: I haven't tried to resubmit the app, but I am like crying, I don't know why, what's happend.

Comment: Did they give any reason for removal though?

Comment: no, there is totally no reason, I am confused.

Comment: Interesting... I think resubmitting is worth a try, and if that doesn't help either, ask support to see if they can provide you with a reason and then you can improve the app based on that

Comment: I have done everything they asked for, also made a video and sent to them.
efore we can complete our review of your app, we need a video that demonstrates the current version, 1.0.0, in use on a physical iOS device.
 
The demo video should: 

- Show your app running on a physical iOS device, not on a simulator. 
- Clearly documents all relevant app features, services, and user permission requests.

Next Steps

Provide a link to the video in the App Review Information

Comment: Add countries and regions. And pricing. It will come back.

Comment: solved, thanks man